# Not able to use Private blockchain network in Safe-Infrastructure

Tags: private-blockchain, gnosis-safe, quorum

i have my own private blockchain deployed via quorum and configured safe-infrastructure also on my local. the issue is whenever i am using Linea Georli testnet network i am able to create safe wallets but when i am using my own quorum private blockchain i am getting error while creating safe wallet.

[image]

Note: my quorum blockchain is also working  i am able to do transactions one account to another via metamask. kindly let me know what i have missed while configuring private quorum blockchain.

Comment: Kindly help me to resolve this issue, i am not able to use my quorum private blockchain with my safe infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Hey inorder to work with safe ui on private blockchain requires other aiding services like txn-service, indexing to be in place. Ensure that other services are up inorder to test

Comment: can you give some more info reagrding same ....or any blogs/Doc. anything.